# Is this the standard way for keeping APNS device token updated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications, keychain

I want to make sure my server always has the up to date APNS device token, which can change under specific circumstances.

Should I save it to the Keychain, and on launch check if it's different, and then update the server if so?

Is that the best way to be doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple actually say NOT to store the device token locally. You call `registerForRemoteNotifications()` when you need the device token. From Apple:

`Never cache a device token; always get the token from the system whenever you need it. If your app previously registered for remote notifications, calling the registerForRemoteNotifications method again does not incur any additional overhead, and iOS returns the existing device token to your app delegate immediately. In addition, iOS calls your delegate method any time the device token changes, not just in response to your app registering or re-registering.`

So what you need to do is register for remote notifications on launch, and send that token to your server. From Apple: 
`Device tokens can change, so your app needs to reregister every time it is launched and pass the received token back to your server.`

You can find more documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW25

Comment: Well that's pretty darn definitive! Thank you.

Comment: I would add that IMO it can be important to cache it. If you cache it then you will know if the OS has changed it (which it does very very very very rarely), in which case then and only then do you need to send the new one to your server. If you don't cache it then the result will be you will have to always send the token to your server every single time your app runs and 99.999999% of the time that will have been unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing, you need to register for push notifications every time the app is launched. Like the documentation from Apple says, you never know when and why the token can/will change.

Second, indeed you can have some code to store locally the token in case of a server error or loss of internet when you try to send it to your server. And this logic can retry with a delay and max try count. But this is pretty overkill and not KISS-like.

What you can do is send it as soon as you get it from didRegisterForPushNotification and store it locally and every time the user of your app does an "update settings" call send it at the same time also.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last bit. What do you mean by updating settings?

Comment: I meant if you have a user concept in you app you might have a call from your app to your server that stores/saves user settings. That would be a good time to also send the device token just on case